# tableview refreshing issue

Tags: java, datepicker, tableview, javafx-8

I have a tableview with three columns start date, end date, and no. of days.
I want a feature such that when I choose start date from datepicker based on no. of days in that row, end date should be calculated and should appear on the table view.
I'm using the following date picker class on start date to achieve above functionality.

```
    package upgradeworkbench.Helper;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;


public class DatePickerProjectInputStart<S, T> extends TableCell<ProjectPlanInput, Date> {

    private DatePicker datePicker;
    private ObservableList<ProjectPlanInput> Data;
    private TableView<ProjectPlanInput> ProjectInputTable;
    public DatePickerProjectInputStart(ObservableList<ProjectPlanInput> listBirthdays,TableView table) {

        super();

        this.Data = listBirthdays;
        this.ProjectInputTable=table;
        if (datePicker == null) {
            createDatePicker();
        }
        setGraphic(datePicker);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                datePicker.requestFocus();
            }
        });


    }

     @Override
        public void updateItem(Date item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            SimpleDateFormat smp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } 

            else {
                if(item!=null)
                {
                setDatepikerDate(smp.format(item));
                setText(smp.format(item));
                }
                setGraphic(this.datePicker);
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            }
        }

    private void setDatepikerDate(String dateAsStr) {

        LocalDate ld = null;
        int jour, mois, annee;

        jour = mois = annee = 0;
        try {
            jour = Integer.parseInt(dateAsStr.substring(0, 2));
            mois = Integer.parseInt(dateAsStr.substring(3, 5));
            annee = Integer.parseInt(dateAsStr.substring(6, dateAsStr.length()));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("setDatepikerDate / unexpected error " + e);
        }

        ld = LocalDate.of(annee, mois, jour);
        datePicker.setValue(ld);
    }

    private void createDatePicker() {
        this.datePicker = new DatePicker();
        datePicker.setPromptText("dd-mm-yyyy");
        datePicker.setEditable(false);

        datePicker.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
            public void handle(Event t) {
                LocalDate date = datePicker.getValue();
                int index = getIndex();
                Date changed_date = Date.from(date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
                SimpleDateFormat smp = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MMM/YYYY");
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date.getDayOfMonth());
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, date.getMonthValue() - 1);
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, date.getYear());

                setText(smp.format(cal.getTime()));
                  commitEdit(cal.getTime());
                 ProjectInputTable.getItems().get(getIndex()).setStartDate(changed_date);
                Date strtDate = changed_date;
                int weekdays = Integer.valueOf(ProjectInputTable.getItems().get(getIndex()).getEstimate());
                        Calendar cald = Calendar.getInstance();
                        cald.setTime(strtDate);
                        int originalDayOfWeek = cald.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                        int numWeeks = weekdays / 5;
                        int remainderDays = weekdays % 5;
                        cald.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, numWeeks * 7 + remainderDays);

                        int adjustmentDays = 0;
                        if (originalDayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
                            adjustmentDays = 1;
                        } else if (originalDayOfWeek + remainderDays > Calendar.FRIDAY) {
                            adjustmentDays = 2;
                        }
                        cald.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, adjustmentDays);
                        Date EndDate = cald.getTime();

                  ProjectInputTable.getItems().get(getIndex()).setEndDate(EndDate);  
                  ProjectInputTable.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
                  ProjectInputTable.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);
                if (null != getData()) {
                    getData().get(index).setStartDate(cal.getTime());
                    getData().get(index).setEndDate(EndDate);
                }

            }
        });

        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

    public ObservableList<ProjectPlanInput> getData() {
        return Data;
    }

    public void setData(ObservableList<ProjectPlanInput> Data) {
        this.Data = Data;
    }

    public DatePicker getDatePicker() {
        return datePicker;
    }

    public void setDatePicker(DatePicker datePicker) {
        this.datePicker = datePicker;
    }

private LocalDate getDate() {
            return getItem() == null ? LocalDate.now() : getItem().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        }
    }
```

The issue I'm facing with this code is that whenever I choose start date of any row, some other row's start date also get displayed. Since I'm using a table view and in that two of my columns have datepicker. So if i want to set end date based on start date, the end date will be visible to me only when i refresh my table. And on refreshing I'm facing the issue mentioned.
I'm using following code to refresh my tableview.

```
ProjectInputTable.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
ProjectInputTable.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);
```

[image: As can be seen in the image, 3rd row start date automatically appears on entering 1st row start date]

Please guide how to resolve this issue.

Comment: How do you estimate the End Date?

Comment: from start date add the estimate days minus weekends will give the end date.

Comment: Can't you just manage this in the model class for your data? I.e. when you set one of the fields (start date, end date, or estimate), update one or both of the others as well, so that everything is consistent.

Comment: According to my requirement, i have to set start date on runtime, based on that end date should be calculated there itself and should appear on the screen. I am setting both start date and end date in runtime, but additional rows gets filled automatically. I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `changeListener` on `startDate` can do the magic for you. You can most probably expose the `datepickers valueProperty`  from the TableRow and bind their values.

Here is a very simple example on how the binding can be achieved.

```
public class DatePickerDemo extends Application {

    private Stage stage;
    private DatePicker startDate;
    private DatePicker endDate;
    private int estimatedDays=10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
        stage.setTitle("DatePickerSample ");
        initUI();
        stage.show();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
        vbox.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;");
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        startDate = new DatePicker();
        endDate = new DatePicker();

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setHgap(10);
        gridPane.setVgap(10);

        Label checkInlabel = new Label("Start Date:");
        gridPane.add(checkInlabel, 0, 0);

        GridPane.setHalignment(checkInlabel, HPos.LEFT);
        gridPane.add(startDate, 0, 1);

        Label checkOutlabel = new Label("End Date:");
        gridPane.add(checkOutlabel, 1, 0);

        GridPane.setHalignment(checkOutlabel, HPos.LEFT);
        gridPane.add(endDate, 1, 1);

        startDate.valueProperty().addListener((ob, ov, nv) -> {
            if(nv!=null){
                endDate.setValue(nv.plusDays(estimatedDays));
            }
        });
        vbox.getChildren().add(gridPane);
    }
}
```

Comment: Earlier also I'm getting the correct end date excluding weekends. The problem is that I have refresh the view in order to see the calculated end date and on refreshing another row start date is getting filled. I tried your solution but still the issue is not resolved.

Comment: Refresh the view? I do not get it.

Comment: You may edit your question and write include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), showing your problem.

Comment: I've added an image just to show what problem I'm facing. You can see there, as I'm entering any value in 1st row, the end date is getting calculated but along with it 3rd row start date cell is getting filled automatically. This keeps happening each time i enter any value in any row. other row is automatically getting filled.